# SOQL to get the last updated product in an opportunity

Tags: soql, opportunity-lineitem

Trying to edit this SOQL so that it picks up the last updated product in an opportunity. Any idea how? Right now it is giving me the very first product that was created.

```
PricebookEntry pbeProduct2 = [SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice, Name, Fee_Percentage_Entry__c 
                                FROM PricebookEntry
                                WHERE Name ='Oil Fee'
                                AND Pricebook2Id  IN (SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Id ='01sA00000004lbRIAT') LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: That filter on `Pricebook2Id` is excessive. Just use `Pricebook2Id = '01s...'`, no inner join required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join) here:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItem
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1
) FROM Opportunity WHERE ...
```

One note, you are using a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) here where it is *much less efficient than a direct filter* on the Id value.

Instead of:

```
WHERE Pricebook2Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Id = '...')
```

Use:

```
WHERE Pricebook2Id = '...'
```

Or even better, remove the hard-coded value:

```
WHERE Pricebook2Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsDefault = true)
```

Now your query conforms to best practice and is portable to other tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC` to sort it from latest to oldest and with `LIMIT 1` you'll get last modified.

For example to get last modified Opportunity Product for Opportunity with id = `<OPPID>` it would be

```
OpportunityLineItem product = [SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
    FROM OpportunityLineItem 
    WHERE Opportunity.Id = '<OPPID>' 
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC 
    LIMIT 1];
```

Side note: This can throw exception as no record could be found.

Comment: but the Opportunity.Id would be a hard code. wouldn't it? I want to avoid giving the opportunity id since it would change very time.

Comment: @HUBBY0716 : If you have Opportunity object you can look for value dynamically `Opportunity.Id =: opp.Id` for example.